# Is there a way to start a Cardano node in Devnet?

Tags: cardano-node, stake-pool, devnet

I'd like to start a Cardano node in Devnet (not Testnet).

I looked for the configuration files [in here](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/13695229/download/1/index.html), but it seems they are not available.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is there even a devnet?

Comment: Yes, I know there is a Devnet because the Hydra POC should be run in Devnet using Docker (check this repo: https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc). What I don't know if it is possible to run cardano-node in Devnet without Docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like devnet refers to your local/private environment.

The Hydra-POC docs refer to it as 'a single Cardano node producing blocks used as a local devnet'

More details about Hydra-POC set up here:
https://hydra.family/head-protocol/docs/getting-started/demo/with-docker/

There are 'With Docker' and 'Without Docker' instructions.

The 'With Docker' portion notes: 'From there, we can run the ./prepare-devnet.sh script to create an initial configuration for our development network'.